# iOS: Several Touch Event on View Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have developped a small application with 2 View .

My first UIView is a Menu containing some images. When I click on one of them, I switch on the Second UIView to display it.

Afterwards, I created a new UIView who is a "menu extension" of my first Menu. I created a UIView but when I put the component "Swipe", the application do not switch to my second new menu.

I would like to know, if Iphone App supports several touch event on the UIView ?

Comment: Do you have your swipe gesture tied to a segue in interface builder?

Comment: Yes of course. I tried on another fresh View Controller. It's working well. I guess that it's not possible to combine several Event Touch on the same View Controller ... someone to confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects of class `UIGestureRecognizer` are attached to a `UIView` object, not to `UIViewController` objects. And it is possible to attach multiple gesture recognizers to a single view, see its `gestureRecognizers` property.
But you have to be careful: If you want a swipe to be recognized, a single tap recognizer might fire before the swipe could be recognized, since the latter requires the move of the finger. Therefore, you can configure multiple gesture recognizers of the same view such that they show the required behavior, e.g. that a single tap recognizer fires only when a swipe recognizer does not fire, etc., see the docs of `UIGestureRecognizer` Class Reference.

Comment: Thx @Reinhard, I wrote mistakes. Corrected! Thx you for all.